# How to pull a variable outside of a function in Google Embed Api

Tags: javascript, function, google-analytics

I'm trying pull some queried data from my Google Analytics accounts, and I've got the query running beautifully. I've run into a problem though, that I can't actually access the query data because it's inside a function. The variable I've assigned to it logs undefined, which leads me to believe that this is a scope problem. However, I've played around with the scope, defining inside and outside the viewSelector function and have been unsuccessful in accessing that data.

My question is this: How can I access the data inside the viewSelector change function from outside the ready function?

```
<div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
<div id="view-selector-container"></div>
<script>
    (function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
        g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
        js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
        fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
    }(window,document,'script'));

    var accounts;
    gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
        gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
            container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
            clientid: 'CLIENT_ID'
        });
        var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
            container: 'view-selector-container'
        });
        viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
// "ids" is the data I want to access
            accounts = ids;
            console.log('1: ' + accounts);
        });

        viewSelector.execute();  
    });


 // This is where I need to access the data and am unable to
    console.log('2: ' + accounts);
</script>
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `ready` function works as expected, any code you execute outside the function will *not* wait until analytics is ready.  You may need to modify where you put your code:

```
<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
    g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
    js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));

var accounts;
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
        container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
        clientid: 'CLIENT_ID'
    });
    var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
        container: 'view-selector-container'
    });
    viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
        accounts = ids;
        console.log('1: ' + accounts);
    });

    viewSelector.execute();  

    // Accounts is ready here:
    console.log('2: ' + accounts);
});


// This is where I need to access the data and am unable to
// `gapi.analytics` not ready yet.
</script>
```

To quote the documentation:

> All other functions should be placed inside the ready callback to
>   ensure the library is loaded before they're invoked.

Comment: Thanks, but I made the slight adjustment and accounts is ONLY available inside the viewSelector.on function.

Comment: Ok, so the variable is outside of the `change` function, however, it is only set *after* the change function has been invoked.  You may need to look at JS closure to understand what's happening here.